# Drush 8.1.2 is not working on Windows

Tags: drush

I have installed Drush 8.1.2 on Windows 7, but it doesn't work. Few command are working, but few are not working.

- `drush uli 1` works
- `drush dl <project name>` works
- `drush en <project name>` doesn't work
- `drush cc all` doesn't work

Running `drush en "module name"`, I get the following:

> Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
>   The drush command 'en fieldupdate' could not be executed.
>   Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.
>   Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
>
> - bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
> - connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
>
>   Drush was attempting to connect to:
>      Drupal version         :  7.34
>      Site URI               :  http://default
>      Database driver        :  mysql
>      Database hostname      :  localhost
>      Database port          :
>      Database username      :  root
>      Database name          :  staticpages
>      PHP configuration      :  C:\xampp\php\php.ini
>      PHP OS                 :  WINNT
>      Drush script           :  C:\Users\ins237\AppData\Roaming\Composer
>                                \vendor\drush\drush\drush
>      Drush version          :  8.1.2
>      Drush temp directory   :  C:/Users/ins237/AppData/Local/Temp
>      Drush configuration    :
>      Drush alias files      :
>      Drupal root            :  C:\xampp\htdocs\cms-staticpages
>      Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
>      Site path              :  sites/default

Comment: I also tried with drush 7.3 and getting same error.

Comment: Honestly, do yourself a favor and start working with a UNIX based OS.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your database cannot be contaced, run `drush status` to make sure of that. If that's the issue, then you should update your settings.php files with the correct ip, I guess 127.0.0.1 for your xampp stack.

Not an answer to your question, but running PHP/Drupal on Windows is just asking for problems. You should look into Vagrant or Docker to run your Drupal sites on Windows, that will save you a lot of pain in the long run AND will make it easier to deploy your sites later on.

Comment: Database connection is okay, if so this will not run on my machine.

Comment: _"`drush uli 1` works"_ This needs database connection to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the **Drupal Console project.*

Drupal Console is abstracted on top of Symfony and such an abstraction provides better cross-platform compatibility.

In this post you can find example commands to completely setup a Drupal installation from console on Windows (without Linux bash, real Command line or Powershell scripts):

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/continuous-integration-and-testing-drupal-appveyor

The sample commands there include:

- Setting up a code base from scratch using Composer
- Installing the website from the command line using "drupal install" command.
- Enabling/downloading modules using composer and the "drupal module:install" command.
- Running drupal tests from the console

> Not an answer to your question, but running PHP/Drupal on Windows is
>   just asking for problems.

It depends on your budget.

If you are doing brochureware/low budget, you are better off not even setting up an environment at all and looking a Platform.sh, Acquia, Pantheon, etc.

Indeed, Wordress is a much better product for such scenarios (low budget/quickies).